# Windows Mobile Compact Framework Designer Inheritance

Tags: c#, windows, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I'm trying to make a form derive from a baseform.

When loading the Form into the Designer, it says Virtual Inheritance is disabled and i cannot have access to controls defined in the basedForm.

Does anyone knows how to enable the virtual inheritance?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

The VS Designer does not support this.